# ion-item-slider buttons not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble with the buttons associated with item sliders using ion-item-sliding. The buttons are displaying below the item pane rather than underneath it (see attached picture). Here is my HTML code snippet that is causing the issue:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <ion-item ng-click="selectProject(project, $index)" ng-class={active: activeProject == project}">
            {{project.title}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="left">
            <button ion-button>
                <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
                Delete
            </button>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

[My buttons display like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD3Bz.png)
[but I want them to display like this](https://www.joshmorony.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ionic-delete-header.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation..

```
<ion-item-options side="left">
  <button ion-button (click)="archive(item)">
    <ion-icon name="archive"></ion-icon>
    Archive
  </button>
</ion-item-options>
```

Source.. [IonicFramework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/)

Comment: This doesn't fix it.